# Como Ler e condicionar uma string em java

Tags: java

eu preciso saber o seguinte:
Quero fazer um programa que Le um numero e em seguida eescreve o nome do numero:
Por exemplo:foi digitado o numero 29340, em seguida aparece: 2-Dois, 9-Nove, 3-Tres, 4-Quatro, 0-Zero.
Estou tentando fazer transformando para String pegando length e com string.equals, mas não estou conseguindo! Pois parece que ele le os números anteriores juntos com os seguintes... Se alguém puder me ajudar eu agradeço

Comment: Misael, clique em [edit] e poste o código que você já tentou e como está ficando a saída.

Comment: String valor = "a", be="b";
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        String Letra=s.next();
       String tmpValor = String.valueOf(Letra);
        String novoValor = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < tmpValor.length(); i++) {
            novoValor = novoValor + tmpValor.substring(i, i+1) + " ";
            if (tmpValor == valor) {
                System.out.println("Letra A");
            }
            else if (tmpValor == be) {
                System.out.println("Letra B");